# numpy searchsorted lexicographic on slice

Tags: python, search, numpy, scipy, binary-search

Suppose I have a numpy array that is already sorted.

```
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
       [2, 2, 3, 2],
       [2, 3, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 5, 5, 5]])
```

I want to do a righthand bisection based on the first *two* columns.

Something like (quasicode) `numpy.searchsorted(x, [2, 2], side='right')` that should return 2, the index between `[2, 2, 3, 2]` and `[2, 3, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
>>> i1 = np.searchsorted(x[:, 0], 2, side='l')
>>> i2 = np.searchsorted(x[i1:, 0], 2, side='r')
>>> i3 = np.searchsorted(x[i1:i1+i2, 1], 2, side='r')
>>> i1 + i3
2
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be i1 = np.searchsorted(x[:, 0], 2, side='r') ; i2 = np.searchsorted(x[i1:, 1], 2, side='r'); return i1 + i2?

Comment: Try it with a first column `[1, 2, 2, 2, 4]` and a second column `[1, 2, 2, 3, 5]`. Your method will return `i1 = 4` and `i2 = 0` for a combined `i1 + i2 = 4` which I don't think is what you want. Doing the three calls you would get `i1 = 1`, `i2 = 3` and `i3 = 2`, for a return of`i1 + i3 = 3`, which I think is correct.